# csv writer issue in Python - how can i remove these elements?

Tags: python

I am scraping this data from a site:

```
title: A title
Description: A description with, a comma.
```

My code is:

```
rows = title, desc   

with open('\scrape.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
    writer.writerow([rows])
```

Expected result:

```
A title | A description with, a comma.
```

But the result I get:

```
('A title', \"A description with, a comma.\")
```

Why is the delimiter ignored? Why do I get the result in parentheses? Can I get rid of the `escapechar='\\'`?

Comment: Where do you see this result?

Comment: what is `rows`? (what *exactly* do you get if you print it?)

Comment: The "result I get" looks like you printed "rows" from within Python, rather than copying in the contents of the output file.  Please be clear which you're showing.

Comment: You're passing a `list` with a single `tuple` in it. Use either `writerows([row])` or `writerow(row)`

Comment: rows is a tuple, why are you wrapping it in a list? `[rows] = [(title, desc)]` try just putting rows without wrapping it as a list e.g: `writer.writerow(rows)`

Comment: rows is the same thing I get in the csv file: ('A title', \"A description with, a comma.\"). Looks like the problem is not with the csv.writer but the way I created rows? I just wanted to add title + desc to the same row in csv and thought this was the way. Sorry I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I overcomplicated things here.

The solution is simply:

```
writer.writerow([title, description])
```

Thanks a lot guys for helping.

Comment: This is basically equivalent to leaving your earlier code intact except for doing `writer.writerow(rows)` not `writer.writerow([rows]`.  The point is that you nested things one level to deep.  `rows = title, desc` creates a tuple.